# Searching Multiple Fields with LINQ Contains or Other

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using LINQ to search multiple fields on a single phrase and I'm using `Contains()` to do this. Up until today, when I noticed that the find method isn't working correctly.

So I'd like to be able to search each of the fields where there is any match. I've done some searching on Google and through SO and found suggestions of using `Any()`? Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
var l = _getData().Select(_marshallData).ToList();
            return l.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(what) || x.Pumpkin.Contains(what) || x.Orange.Contains(what) || x.Tomato.Contains(what)).ToList();
```

Please excuse the stupid field names, I've had to change them for confidentiality.

Comment: Wait, so are you looking for a way to enumerate through all the fields in `x` without having to type them all??

Comment: Good question. I had a problem like this today in a project that had to do lookups on an Oracle DB and match with results with two tables on a SQL Server DB and then summing the results for a report. I ended up doing most of the queries as SQL statements since the Contains statements weren't performing well with EF or my results weren't coming out right.

Comment: I put out to `x` so I can run Contains on the select fields - but there are many other fields within `x` that I'm not interested in searching.  What are you suggesting as an alternative?

Comment: I created a nuget package to address this very issue called [SearchExtensions](http://ninjanye.github.io/SearchExtensions/stringsearch.html#containing-search).  It may help others that land here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're materializing the data already you could do this:

```
var l = _getData().Select(_marshallData).AsEnumerable();
return l.Where(x => new[] { x.Name, x.Pumpkin, x.Orange, x.Tomato }.Any(s => s.Contains(what)));
```

But if you're using an ORM (like Entity Framework) this trick probably won't work (since there's a good chance this can't be converted to a SQL expression). In this case, you're original solution is fine, but it would probably be better to do this *before* you materialize the data.

```
return _getData()
    .Where(x => 
        x.Name.Contains(what) || x.Pumpkin.Contains(what) || 
        x.Orange.Contains(what) || x.Tomato.Contains(what))
    .Select(_marshallData)
    .AsEnumerable();
```

Of course the field names here might be different, since the parameter `x` is probably a different type. Without further information, it's up to you to write this filter correctly.

Note that in both examples, I've eliminated the calls to `ToList`. Unless you absolutely need the result to a `List<T>` this is probably unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer p.s.w.g ;)  The data from SQL is already contained (and cached even further back) within `l` in this case. So this would be pure LINQ. I'll try your suggestions - thanks again.

Comment: Turns out that I was doing practically what you were doing, but what I failed to realise was `Contains()` is of course case sensitive - `x.Name.Contains('FISH')` is not the same as `x.Name.Contains('FisH')`, that was my mistake. Thanks - it was your code that made me finally get to the answer.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks for that. But what if I had to write the same thing for `SomeNonStringProperty`. Is there any way to do that, because AFAIK we can't use `.ToString()` for a Lamba expression. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Agent007 Have you tried it? It definitely works for in-memory queries (note the `AsEnumerable`), and it may work in other query providers, depending on what you use.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Sorry, I should have been more specific. I was trying this with LINQ-to-SQL but couldn't get it work. Can you please suggest anything?

Comment: @Agent007 First off, I wonder why you're comparing numbers or dates to strings anyway. If something is stored as a number/date, it should probably be treated as a number/date, and not a string. If this is indeed a valid use case, try using [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487127.aspx) (you may need to cast the column's value)